# Dimension of Vector Space (Polynomial)

Tags: polynomials, vector-spaces

I was asked by a friend to: "Find the dimension of the vector space consisting of all polynomials in $n$-variables of degree at most $k$".Now, my response to him was that since the basis consists of all monomials $\ x^{i_1}_1\cdots x^{i_n}_n $ such that $\sum_{j=1}^n{i_
j}\le k $; what we really are looking for is the number of solutions to the inequality. This, if I am not mistaken, is the same as the number of solutions to ${i_1}+...+{i_n}+{i_{n+1}}=k$,which in turn is the same as to choose $n$ objects from $n+k$ which can be done in $\binom{n+k}{k}=\binom{n+k}{n}$. Thus, my claim is that $\binom{n+k}{n}$ is the dimension. Is this the case? I would appreciate to see if anyone has a different approach to the question.

Comment: the argument looks fine to me.  The lower limit of a sum looks better using the underline to ask for a subscript than \limits.

Answer (score 1):

Just echoing the comment of Ross Millikan here: Yes, you argument is correct.

I am not aware of any way to do this which is fundamentally different, and indeed, this way seems like the most simple one.